# Does Google login in Laravel Socialite contain user's phone number?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7, laravel-socialite

I implemented Google login using Socialite in Laravel. The example I used only contains the user's name, google_id, email and profile picture. Is there a way to get the phone number from the Google callback? Or does it even contain the number? Here's the function that handles the callback:

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    try {
        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect('/login');
    }
    // check if they're an existing user
    $existingUser = User::where('email', $user->email)->first();
    if($existingUser){
        // log them in
        auth()->login($existingUser, true);
    } else {
        // create a new user
        $newUser                  = new User;
        $newUser->name            = $user->name;
        $newUser->email           = $user->email;
        $newUser->google_id       = $user->id;
        $newUser->avatar          = $user->avatar;
        $newUser->avatar_original = $user->avatar_original;
        $newUser->save();
        auth()->login($newUser, true);
    }
    return redirect()->to('/');
}
```

Comment: By default socialite doesn't provide phone number, it depends on the permissions you have set in the app created in google console.

Comment: @Cyril To be clear, userPrincipalName is NOT a email, even though it looks like one and is mapped here as one. [mail](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Providers/blob/master/src/Microsoft/Provider.php#L84) is actually the email address field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is not possible. You should add a middleware that verifies your users have a phone. This way, you are sure your users will provide a phone no matter how they registered.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported.

Looking at [the provider](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Providers/blob/master/src/Google/Provider.php#L20), we can see it is using [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/). And so the [phone_number claim](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims) should be available. But as per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#obtaininguserprofileinformation), Google has it's own supported claims:

```
"claims_supported": [
    "aud",
    "email",
    "email_verified",
    "exp",
    "family_name",
    "given_name",
    "iat",
    "iss",
    "locale",
    "name",
    "picture",
    "sub"
],
```

These claims are later [mapped](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Providers/blob/master/src/Google/Provider.php#L71) using:

```php
protected function mapUserToObject(array $user)
{
    return (new User())->setRaw($user)->map([
        'id'       => $user['sub'],
        'nickname' => Arr::get($user, 'name'),
        'name'     => $user['name'],
        'email'    => $user['email'],
        'avatar'   => $user['picture'],
    ]);
}
```